# How to Hide and show the element on specific section in the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my website, I have some popup kind of float model it's fixed at bottom of the page. on that page, I have different sections. when I scrolling on the website that modal will visible only in some sections and for other sections, it should hide.

Example in this below code that floats popup should hide banner and footer sections while scrolling on that page. but if I present or viewing in the rest of the section, it should visible. I want this kind of thing. anyone, please help me to achieve this.

I tried using JavaScript but it's not working, this code hide popup modal for all the sections.

```
var mainbanner = document.querySelector(".banner"); 
if (mainbanner.top != window.self) {
    document.getElementByClassName("float-popup").style.display = "none ";
 }
```

```css
section{
  height:300px;
  text-align:center;
}
section:nth-child(odd) {
  background:#acacac;
}
section:nth-child(even) {
  background:#e47d7d;
}
p{
  color:red;
}
.float-popup{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  background:#000;
  text-align:center;
}
body{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <section class="banner">
    <p>banner content</p>
  </section>
  <section class="services">
    <p>services content</p>
  </section>
  <section class="features">
    <p>features content</p>
  </section>
  <section class="footer">
    <p>footer content</p>
  </section>

  <div class="float-popup">
    <p>float content</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even I was looking for a solution to the exactly same problem, and I found the solution to it. I tried some code, and it worked fine. This would work:

```js
function checkFloatingDiv() {
  var section1 = document.querySelector('.banner');
  var position1 = section1.getBoundingClientRect();
  var section2 = document.querySelector('.footer');
  var position2 = section2.getBoundingClientRect();

  //Checking whether the specified sections are visible
  //If any of them is visible, then show the float content. Else, hide it.
  if (position1.top < window.innerHeight && position1.bottom >= 0) {
    //Show the floating element
    document.querySelector('.float-popup').style.display = "block";
    return;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.float-popup').style.display = "none";
  }

  if (position2.top < window.innerHeight && position2.bottom >= 0) {
    //Show the floating element
    document.querySelector('.float-popup').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.float-popup').style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Run the function on scroll
window.addEventListener("scroll", checkFloatingDiv);
// Run the function on load, if any elements are already visible without scrolling
window.addEventListener("load", checkFloatingDiv);
```

```css
section {
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

section:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #acacac;
}

section:nth-child(even) {
  background: #e47d7d;
}

p {
  color: red;
}

.float-popup {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <p>banner content</p>
</section>
<section class="services">
  <p>services content</p>
</section>
<section class="features">
  <p>features content</p>
</section>
<section class="footer">
  <p>footer content</p>
</section>

<div class="float-popup" style="display: none;">
  <p>float content</p>
</div>
```

P/S: In this code, I have taken an example that the float content would be visible only when the "banner" and the "footer" content would be visible on screen. You can definitely change it as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

getElementByClassName isn't a function try this instead

```
document.getElementsByClassName("float-popup")[0].style.display = "none";
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but if I use your code this will hide for all the sections. i want while scrolling in banner and footer that popup should hide and for other sections, it should show in scrolling time.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementByClassName` is not a JavaScript function, you seem to be meaning the `document.getElementsByClassName` function (notice the Element**s**), which returns an array. So if there is only one element with that class name, just get the 0th index of that array.

Like this:

```js
    document.getElementsByClassName("float-popup")[0].style.display = "none ";
```

```js
const mainbanner = document.getElementsByClassName("banner")[0]; // I'm assuming this is what "mainbanner" variable is

if (mainbanner.top != window.self) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("float-popup")[0].style.display = "none";
 }
```

```css
section{
  height:300px;
  text-align:center;
}
section:nth-child(odd) {
  background:#acacac;
}
section:nth-child(even) {
  background:#e47d7d;
}
p{
  color:red;
}
.float-popup{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  background:#000;
  text-align:center;
}
body{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <section class="banner">
    <p>banner content</p>
  </section>
  <section class="services">
    <p>services content</p>
  </section>
  <section class="features">
    <p>features content</p>
  </section>
  <section class="footer">
    <p>footer content</p>
  </section>

  <div class="float-popup">
    <p>float content</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this hides the popup modal for all the sections. I asked it should hide while scrolling only banner and footer but if I present in services or features it should visible in float bottom.

Comment: All I did was fix your JavaScript that you didn't implement properly `getElementsByClassName(...)[0]`

Comment: while scrolling that is hiding for all the sections. I need it should hide only sections.

Comment: Well if you want it to update, your JavaScript will need to be in a loop of some kind

Comment: Or bind an [event listener to scrolling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, that you what to some kind of work when a certain div (banner/footer) is visible in the viewport. If that is what you are looking for you can use this.

```
function isInViewport(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)

    );
}


const banner = document.querySelector('.banner');
const footer = document.querySelector('.footer');
const floatPopup = document.querySelector('.float-popup');

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const floatPopupDisplay = isInViewport(banner) || isInViewport(footer) ?
       "block" : 'none';

    floatPopup.style.display = floatPopupDisplay;

}, {
    passive: true
});
```

Comment: yeah...whatever you are saying it's right. but your code also not working.